# React proxy: Couldn't connect to home route, while other routes work perfectly

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, react-router-dom, mern

I am using the proxy 'http://localhost:5000' in package.json.

Frontend code,

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Nav from './components/nav';
import Home from './components/home';
import Business from './components/business';

const [articles, setArticles] = React.useState('');
const [url, setUrl] = React.useState("/");
        
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {setArticles(data)})
}, [url]);
        
console.log(url);
function changeTopic(e, sub) {
  setUrl(`/${sub}`);
}

   return (
     <BrowserRouter>
          <Nav change = {changeTopic}/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home articles={articles} />} />   
            <Route path='/topics/:id' element={<Business articles={articles} />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
)
export default App;
```

React router links to navigate to different urls
Nav.js

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Nav(props){
    
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to = "/" onClick = {(e) => props.change(e,'')}>Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to = "/topics/business" onClick = {(e) => props.change(e,'topics/business')}>Business</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

home.js file

```
export default function Home(props){
    
    return (
        <div>
          <p>{props.articles.data}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It seems that no fetch request is made for the home address.
Also in the browser the console logs 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' when the home link is clicked.
The Business links works fine.

Backend code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());

app.use('/', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.url)
    res.json({"data" : "inside home"})
});

app.use('/topics/business',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.url)
    res.json({"data" : "inside topics"})
});

app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that the app ***can't*** navigate to `"/"` path and render `<Home articles= {articles} />`? Or that it can and that there's some issue with your proxy/server? From what I can tell there's absolutely nothing wrong with the `react-router` code, so my guess is that any issues you have are with the `fetch` and the request URL and/or the server and what requests it responds to and handles. It might also be helpful to us if you could post a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've better context where this state lives and where/how it's updated.

Comment: The app **can** navigate to "/" but can't render <Home/> component. The issue is with the request url and fetch statement while using proxy, if i don't use a proxy, everything is fine. At the backend side the console logs req.url for the "/topics" route while it doesn't for the "/" route.

Comment: Ok, so this isn't a `react-router-dom` issue then. What *should* your backend do for GET requests on `"/"`? What is the frontend requesting? Please share the backend code and more clearly explain what you want the code to accomplish.

Comment: I used a console log in the backend to get the req.url for each of the routes, it logs the route for the "/topics route" but not for the "/" route. This issue emerged after using the proxy statement in package.json. The backend returns the same type of data for all the routes.

Comment: Can you check the `"http://localhost:5000/"` endpoint independent from the app, i.e. via Postman/etc? What is the network request made from the app, i.e. check the request URL in the browser's devtools in the network tab? Have you ensured both the app and server are running your latest code changes? You may need to kill and restart both the app's development server and the backend server. FYI, `fetch` returns Promise rejections, so you'll probably want to catch and handle these so your app doesn't crash and prevent page access.

Comment: I checked the endpoint "http://localhost:5000/" via postman, it is getting the desired response, and in the network tab the headers section shows the request url - "http://localhost:3000/". Both the app and server respond to latest code changes, I added the catch part but that's not called instead the second then statement logs "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" in the console. Also after clicking the "topics/business" link the <Business/> component persists even if i click the home link, while on reloading no <Home/> component is rendered.

Comment: Just for kicks, what if you changed the home route to `"/home"` and update the backend to have a matching endpoint, is the GET request made successfully then and render the `Home` component? If that works then I think there's just some conflict between your frontend on `"/"` and a request to the backend. It's odd you mentioned though that in the network tab you saw `"localhost:3000"` instead of the expected port 5000.

Comment: I did change the home route on both ends and everything works fine, it was just that I couldn't understand the earlier situation with the route '/'... Well thanks anyway........

Comment: So I suggest then to keep the frontend home page route on `"/"` and just explicitly check that path value prior to making the GET request to a special non-`"/"` backend endpoint.